# Post request to download file of a webserver from a WPF App (C#)

Tags: c#, php, wpf

In the following code, I can send a POST request for the webserver and get a response:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async static Task<int> User(string email, string password)
{
    email = email.ToLower();
    string theEmail = Cryptor.Encrypt(email);
    string thePass = Cryptor.Encrypt(password);
    try
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "email", theEmail },
            { "password", thePass }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://url...", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Globals.USER = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserObject>(responseString);
        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get a file sending a POST request and then save this file in a specific folder in the user's computer?

(What would be the PHP code to return the file after receiving the user's credentials and how would I get this file in the C# code?)

For example:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    // Validate user
    //  .
    //  .
    //  .
    // Until here it's ok

    // Now what would be the code to return the file?
    // For example, a file from the following path: "user-folder/docs/image.png"

}else{
    echo 'error';
    die;
}
```

And in the WPF App, in C# usually I would read the response like this:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://url...", content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But how would it be to get the file back?

Comment: Are you asking, how to send a file via PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending files is generally done by transferring the content as binary data. If you don't explicitly send text data, using `HttpClient.ReadAsString` is useless. Either read the response content as byte array or as stream.

Sending the file using the [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function:

```php
$file = 'user-folder/docs/image.png';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' .filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

There are alternatives e.g., using cURL etc.

To request and save the file on your C# client you can handle the response content directly as `Stream` or `byte` array:

```cs
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://url...", content);
var destinationFilePath = "image.png";
await using var destinationStream = File.Create(destinationFilePath);

// Handle the response directly as Stream
await using Stream sourceStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);

// Alternatively, create the Stream manually
// or write the byte array directly to the file
byte[] sourceData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
await destinationStream.WriteAsync(sourceData);
```

Comment: This works perfectly when the PHP file is in the root directory, but when I try to give the file a relative path, like ```$file = '../user-folder/docs/image.png'```, it downloads a empty file. Do you know why?

Comment: The script does not automatically resolves relative paths for you. The path is always relative to the loctaion of the script file. You can get the executing folder calling getcwd(). You can call chdir() to change the folder getcwd() returns. You can use the constant ____DIR____ to get the script's working directory. dirname(%path%) returns the parent directory of the argument. Server variables: $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]: HTTP root. $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]: relative script path. and more. So, you must assemble the absolute path dynamically.

Comment: I have found this resource for you. You can consult the PHP reference for more details on each function or system variable. https://code-boxx.com/php-absolute-relative-path/

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this all works perfectly XD. I thought I could put the "../" to go up a folder in the file path but apparently not. I ended up using like this: ```$file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/user-folder/docs/image.png';``` cause my php file is actually inside anoher folder.

Comment: Nice, I'm hapy I could help you. Good luck with your project!